# :after pseudo-element and tags

Tags: html, css

I just created a simple page where I tried to emulate ajax with CSS. For doing that, I wanted to create invisible radio-buttons with visible labels, an external CSS-file should be loaded as soon as the user clicks on a label. There is just one problem: Tags are printed out as plain text inside the class. Is there a way to handle that?

edit: As requested, my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
    <title>Demo: Ajax without JS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #loader:checked:after{
            content:'<link class="sheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="external.css"/>';
        }
    </style>
</head><body>
    <div class="rad"><input type="radio" id="loader"/><label for="loader">Loader</label></div>
</body></html>
```

Yes, it is as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply speaking, you cannot do this. Generated content is viewed as presentation, and is thus not actually inserted into the DOM.

> Note that the generated content is only rendered—it doesn’t appear in the DOM tree. In other words, generated content doesn’t alter the document as such—only the presentation.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/content

Thus everything you try to insert will be rendered in plain text. Another implication of this is that whatever you generate with `content` you cannot manipulate with Javascript. So you're stuck with Javascript for this sort of things.

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/content

Comment: Is there no way like adding the href-attribute to a given sub-element? (Besides: is that possible with a-tags?)

Comment: @FB55 Not entirely sure what you're getting at here, but if you want to manipulate the DOM in any way, such as changing the attribute of an element, you **have** to use Javascript